# How to change the css class of list which is inside an asp repeater when clicking an asp link button?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, list, repeater

I am trying to build a three level left navigation for my application using asp.net repeater and html list

I have three nested repeater with a linkbutton inside

when i click the linkbutton the list class should be active ( i have css for this active class).I am not good in Jquery

below is my code ( now i used only two repeater),Kindly help me how can i do this?

```html
<ul class="nav nav-list mb-xl show-bg-active">
                                 <asp:repeater ID="rep1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                         <li class="">
                                             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Menu") %>'></asp:LinkButton>                                                                                      
                                                 <asp:repeater ID="rep2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                                         <ul>
                                                        <li>  
                                                              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CommandArgument="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Menu") %>'></asp:LinkButton>                                                                                                    
                                                        </li> </ul>
                                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                                 </asp:repeater>
                                                 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KTCWEBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT NAVIAGATE_1.Menu FROM NAVIAGATE INNER JOIN NAVIAGATE AS NAVIAGATE_1 ON NAVIAGATE.ID = NAVIAGATE_1.ParentID WHERE (NAVIAGATE.Menu = @menu)">
                                                     <SelectParameters>
                                                         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LinkButton1" Name="menu" PropertyName="text" />
                                                     </SelectParameters>
                                                 </asp:SqlDataSource>   
                                         </li>
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:repeater>
                                 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KTCWEBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Menu, ParentID, ID FROM NAVIAGATE WHERE (NOT (ParentID IS NULL)) AND (ParentID = 2)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                             </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's been a while since I've done ASP.Net controls but...

Your inner lists would need to bind the Enabled property to something in your Controller. Then when something is clicked you just set that binding to false. This should in turn disable all those buttons and if your css is written correctly (tier2:disabled) it should pick it up correctly.

That said, if this is a new application, stop using ASP.NET controls, it should have been killed a long time ago. HTML + CSS + ReactJs or KnockoutJs is the way to go now-a-days!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using asp.net for my application and it is not a new application.I created the menu and is working fine.But i want to do the small thing i want to activate the currently clicked item.I think there is some Jquery script can do this.